# How to specify column data type when writing Spark DataFrame to Oracle

Tags: apache-spark, jdbc, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I want to write a Spark DataFrame to an Oracle table by using Oracle JDBC driver. My code is listed below:

```
url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@servername:sid"
mydf.write \
    .mode("overwrite") \
    .option("truncate", "true") \
    .format("jdbc") \
    .option("url", url) \
    .option("driver", "oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver") \
    .option("createTableColumnTypes", "desc clob, price double") \
    .option("user", "Steven") \
    .option("password", "123456") \
    .option("dbtable", "table1").save()
```

What I want is to specify the desc column to clob type and the price column to double precision type. But Spark show me that the clob type is not supported. The length of desc string is about 30K. I really need your help. Thanks

Comment: https://github.com/apache/spark/commit/c7911807050227fcd13161ce090330d9d8daa533

Comment: Try creating target table first.

Comment: I did. The target table is pre-created.

Answer (score 0):

As per this [note](https://github.com/apache/spark/commit/c7911807050227fcd13161ce090330d9d8daa533) specifies that there are some data types that are not supported. If the target table is already created with CLOB data type then createTableColumnTypes may be redundant. You can  check if writing to a CLOB column is possible with spark jdbc if table is already created.

Answer (score 0):

Create your table in mysql with your required schema , now use mode='append' and save records .

mode='append' only insert records without modify table schema.